# How to bootstrap weighted mean in a loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics-bootstrap, weighted-average

I would like to run a bootstrap of a weighted mean in a for loop (I don’t think I can use ‘apply’ because it concerns a weighted mean). I would only need to store the resulting standard errors in a dataframe. Another post provided the code for how to calculate the weighted mean in a bootstrap ([bootstrap weighted mean in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46231261/bootstrap-weighted-mean-in-r)), and works perfectly:

```
library(boot)
 
mtcarsdata = mtcars #dataframe for data 
mtcarsweights = rev(mtcars) #dataframe for weights

samplewmean <- function(d, i, j) {
  d <- d[i, ]
  w <- j[i, ]
  return(weighted.mean(d, w))   
}

results_qsec <- sd(boot(data= mtcarsdata[, 6, drop = FALSE], 
                     statistic = samplewmean, 
                     R=10000, 
                     j = mtcarsweights[, 6 , drop = FALSE])[[2]], na.rm=T)
results_qsec
```

To then run it in a loop, I tried:

```
outputboot = matrix(NA, nrow=11, ncol=1)
for (k in 1:11){
  outputboot[1,k] = sd(boot(data= mtcarsdata[, k, drop = FALSE], 
                       statistic = samplewmean, 
                       R=10000, 
                       j = mtcarsweights[, k, drop = FALSE])[[2]], na.rm=T)
}
outputboot
```

But this doesn't work. The first output isn’t even correct. I suspect the code can’t work with two iterators: one for looping over the columns and the other for the sampling with replacement.

I hope anyone could offer some help.

Comment: So you basically want to not only bootstrap one column, but all mtcars columns and get their weighted mean?

Comment: Whenever you can calculate sth. in one step for each column you can use `apply`, `map` and friends. This should be the case for the weighted mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will calculate the standard deviation of all bootstraps for each column of the table `mtcarsdata` weighted by `mtcarsweights`.

Since we can calculate the result in one step, we can use `apply` and friends (here: `purrr:map_dbl`)

```r
library(boot)
library(purrr)

set.seed(1337)

mtcarsdata <- mtcars # dataframe for data
mtcarsweights <- rev(mtcars) # dataframe for weights

samplewmean <- function(d, i, j) {
  d <- d[i, ]
  w <- j[i, ]
  return(weighted.mean(d, w))
}

mtcarsdata %>%
  ncol() %>%
  seq() %>%
  map_dbl(~ {
    # .x is the number of the current column
    sd(boot(
      data = mtcarsdata[, .x, drop = FALSE],
      statistic = samplewmean,
      R = 10000,
      j = mtcarsweights[, .x, drop = FALSE]
    )[[2]], na.rm = T)
  })
#>  [1]  0.90394218  0.31495232 23.93790468  6.34068205  0.09460257  0.19103196
#>  [7]  0.33131814  0.07487754  0.07745781  0.13477355  0.27240347
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>